# Can I google search a word of specific length?

Tags: google-search

I am trying to search a term on google knowing its starting 2 characters and the word length but not the proper spelling. The * wild card only place hold a word or letters but not letter of specific length. Is there even a solution? I remember back in the old days there is "?" that placement a letter in a search terms...

Comment: Your going about this wrong, searching like this is Google would be too vague, you need to figure out the exact (or really close) spelling of the word first... For example, if you know the word is 5 characters and begins with *sp*, there are 101 possible matches in just the English language, did you mean space, spicy, split, spell, speed, etc. Google is good, but not so good that it can read your mind... yet.

Comment: @acejavelin not yet but with the cache enabled it can go closer... To KMC you can use [crossword solver](http://www3.oneacross.com/) resource to help it.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Just go for it? Google will automatically suggest the proper spelling or sometimes even search for it by default. You really need to find out how to spell it before (really) searching for it.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly not with Google, but you can with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

Using the [*"find words matching a pattern"*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/WordsAndLinguistics.html) feature, use underscores ('_') as placeholders for a wildcard character.

Comment: Well thanks. Perhaps I did not explain it best. I am searching for content (e.g. pictures, articles), not definition. +1 still for a nice, new resource.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try this https://www.google.com/advanced_search 
Also this **allintext:theword i am looking for**
And I believe that **"word"** (with double quotes) will also do the trick.